# Use mvc display template in kendo grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got Kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeType>()
.Columns(columns =>
{
    (...)
    columns.Bound(customer => customer.IsActive);
}
```

and I've got an mvc display template (Views/Shared/DisplayTemplate/bool.cshtml)

```
@model bool
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model, new { disabled = "true" })
```

(I tried also with Boolean as a type and template file name)

This works perfectly outside a grid but in grid true/false is shown (that comes from default mvc display template I suppose).

How make kendo grid to use appropriate display template?

(Settings UIHint doesn't help)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.GrasaDielectrica).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= GrasaDielectrica ? checked='checked' : '' # disabled='disabled' ></input>")
```

Comment: I believe that is the only way it can be done. Take a look at [Telerik's documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-troubleshooting.html#BooleanCheckBoxesAjax). If you have found another way to do it, please do share it. I'm curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of found a way, but it is far from ideal because the `ViewModel` must only have `string` members for this to work....and we're really just using a partial view...

`DisplayTemplate.cshtml`:

```
@model ViewModel
@Html.Partial("PartialView", Model)
```

`PartialView.cshtml`:

```
@model ViewModel
@* write schtml here *@
```

`KendoGuid.cshtml`

```
...
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(x => x.GridViewModelField)
        .ClientTemplate("PartialView", new ViewModel
        {
            ViewModelField = "#=GridViewModelField#",
        }).ToHtmlString());
})
...
```